# what does "';' expected" mean?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Pr_function_2_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pr_function_2_);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }
}
```

here is error messages.

> C:\Upload\MyApplication2\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\Pr_function_2_Activity.java:14:
>   error: ';' expected
>           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>                                  ^ C:\Upload\MyApplication2\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\Pr_function_2_Activity.java:14:
>   error: ';' expected
>           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

when i click the messages, cursor is on `"protected void onCreate('here'Bundle savedInstanceState'here')"`

why error is there? ; is required on statement's end, isn't it?

anyway i want to resolve this error. thanks your help.

Comment: Well currently you're trying to declare one method inside another. That's not valid in Java. Why do you have a `main` method at all?

Answer (score 4):

You should really remove the `public static void main(String []args)`, it's not needed in Android. That's why the compiler is complaining, you're putting a method (`onCreate`) inside another method and you don't even need the latter

Answer (score 0):

You don't require `main()` as it is part of Android Framework and you don't need to explicitly define it and it does mapping to appropriate activity. The `onCreate()` is for android activity as `main()` is for a java program. I hope the error goes away on removal of the `main()`.

Comment: onCreate() for android is main() for java. it's new data. thanks you sir